# How to get data from two related tables in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5, query-builder

I've got two models Employees and Departments, i would like to get the all the data from the employee including it's department, something like this:

```
SELECT e.Firstname, e.Surname, e.Age, d.Name as Department FROM Employees as e INNER JOIN Departments as d ON e.Department = d.ID;
```

The result of that is:

```
------------------------------------------
| Firstname | Surname | Age | Department |
------------------------------------------
| John      | Doe     | 25  | Finance    |
```

How could i get the same result in Laravel 5?

I know that i can get all the data of a model like this:

```
$data = Employees::all();
```

But i need the Department column as the value of the parent table.

Using the *Query Builder* it look like this

```
 DB::table('Employees')
            ->join('Departments', 'Employees.Department', '=', 'Departments.ID')
            ->select('Employees.Firstname', 'Employees.Surname', 'Employees.Age', 'Departments.Name')
            ->get();
```

And using Eloquent it look like this

Model

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Departments','Department','ID');
}
```

Controller

```
$data->employees = Employees::with('department')->get();
```

---

Using the Query builder i can pass the data through `@include` and access to it like this:

app.blade.php

```
@include('Club.index.employees',['employees'=>$data->employees])
```

employees.blade.php

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
    @include('Club.index.member',['employee'=>$employee])
@endforeach
```

member.blade.php

```
<h3>{{ $employee->Firstname }}</h3>
<p class="member-surname">{{ $employee->Surname }}</p>
...
```

And it works, but when i use Eloquent it doesn't display the fields from the parent like `Departments.Name` in this case, i don't know if i'm missing something when calling it in the view.
Also i would like to know how could i use aliases for the table columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your model Employee create a function department

```
public function department()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Department');
  }
```

Then in your controller do like this

```
$results = Employee::with('department')->get();
```

This is how you will get all the departments of the employee, but make sure both the table are related on a foreign key basis

Comment: And how could i set the aliases ?

Comment: This doesn't work, The query generates an error, it generates this query: `select * from departments where departments.employees_id in (1, 2)`. What i want is the data from Employees not from Departments